# Is there a notion of tensors (vectors, matrices, etc) as just structured data?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, category-theory, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Vectors are whatever satisfy the vector space axioms. Matrices are linear maps between vectors. Higher order tensors are multilinear maps. These are the standard conceptions of (multi)linear algebra.

But coming from a computational standpoint, is there any notion of a tensor as just grid-structured data? I.e., it is common to think of a grayscale image as a matrix where each element is a greyscale pixel value. In this case, the matrix is *data* and to think of it as a (linear) map just makes things confusing. Moreover, it is also natural to represent grayscale video data as a 3rd order tensor where each "frontal slab/slice" is a (matrix) frame of the video. To think of this as a multilinear map seems to suggest more than just a static blob of structured data, but the latter is all I want to work with.

So is there any notion of tensors as just static structured data blobs rather than as multilinear maps?

Comment: You have to ask yourself what _utility_ you get out of representing 2D structured data as a matrix. The power of linear algebra comes from the fact that rectangular arrays of numbers codify linear maps. It is true that there can be some utility in matrices which do not obviously represent linear transformations. For example, in Machine Learning one often collects $m$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ into an $m \times n$ matrix which can provide some utility. In other contexts (e.g. numerical PDE), even when the data is in a natural rectangular array, we always use the vector of data rather than a matrix.

Comment: So basically there's this really annoying thing where there's no analogue of the distinction between matrices and linear operators for tensors; both the concrete thing and the abstract thing just get called "tensors." We really should have two different names but we don't. So the short answer is yes, people do think of tensors as just being big arrays, but only because they don't have a separate word for these for some reason.

Comment: Matrices are *not* linear maps. They are two-dimensional arrays that can be used, among other things, to represent linear maps on vector spaces.

Comment: What you are looking is some kind of operators over the data, just like the denoising mask filters used in images, which over tensors do not exists. But they could be defined for an specific application, and work with those operators, for example, denoising a tensor capture (an XD video).  I think this would be a bit broad and those operators should be customized to your own best suit.